# Calling a view with function

Tags: java, android

All the views a PRE-STATED, I am not making another view...
other than that what I need i hope is relatively simple, I need to be able to change a element on a  View but be able to all that view thought a function.
Tried it got to this

```
callElement(ElementName).setProgress(Elementi);
```

and ended up trying to go about this with

```
public View callElement(String Element){
    View Dan; 
    Dan = Element + "ChangeNote"; //the View "is HPChangeNote but i want to also put in ManaChangeNote"
    return Dan;
}
```

that diden't end up working thought.
you think you know?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What "element" are you trying to change in a view? Is it another view? What is the parent view, a layout?

Comment: What is `HPChangeNote` ? `TextView`?

Comment: `HPChangeNote` is a `TextView`, there is also a `ProgressBar` i need to change the progress to. I would like to be able to run them them thought the same function but if not that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch. Dan cannot be View and String. Try the following:

```
public String callElement(String Element){
    String Dan; 
    Dan = Element + "ChangeNote"; 
    return Dan;
}
```

Then for the view (call it mView) (could be TextView or EditText ..) you can settext like:

```
mView.setText(callElement("Mana"));
```

The result of the view would be ManaChangeNote.

or

```
mView.setText(callElement("HPChangeNote Mana"));
```

The result of the view would be HPChangeNote ManaChangeNote.